# Firebase: How to translate a device token into a FCM token

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use the Firebase for push notifications. However, I have hit the block, namely I couldn't do that thing in iOS. I attempted two approaches of both

```
Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .prod) and InstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: InstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
```

In 2nd

```
application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)
```

with `Firebase` imported.

What should I do?

EDIT:
This is a supplemental information, the error message is like this.
**Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1003 "(null)"**
I googled, but there is no relavant information.

Comment: I am having same problem if you have solved can you please post the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you're close. Here's what happens right now in the Firebase 4.0 version of Cloud Messaging...

1. When you call `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()`, iOS will request an APNs certificate, just like any ol' iOS app.
2. Assuming you haven't turned method swizzling off (and you probably haven't), Firebase will automatically exchange that APNs token for an FCM token in its own swizzled `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method.
3. When *that* exchange is done, Firebase can let your app know. It used to be that the only way it did this was by creating an NSNotification of type `kFIRMessagingRegistrationTokenRefreshNotification`. But these days, it can also let you know through the `MessagingDelegate`. So the easiest thing to do is to declare your AppDelegate a messaging delegate by calling...

   ```
   Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
   ```

   ...and then implementing the `messaging(_:didRefreshRegistrationToken)` method.

   ```
   func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
     print("Look! I have an FCM token! \(fcmToken)")
   }
   ```

So the tl;dr is that you don't need to exchange the APNs token for an FCM token manually, you just need to set up your delegate to be notified when the FCM library does this for you.

Comment: Before you answered, my setting about the swizzling was on! So, I had to handle all things, but now I turn off and make my `AppDelegate` class conform to `MessageDelegate` class, following your advice.   And in `messaging(_:didRefreshRegistrationToken)` , I wrote an initialization.  However, `messaging(_:didRefreshRegistrationToken)` is not called after executing `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()`.  Still my `application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)` is called.  Why?

Comment: I have the same problem, but I turned Method Swizzling off, and the documentation says that `didRefreshRegistrationToken` is only available for IOS 10+ , what should I do for versions below that?, and I used `Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true` instead of `connect` and `disconnect` methods but I cant get the notification from `Notification.Name.MessagingRegistrationTokenRefreshed` when I disable method swizzling anyway, its killing me :(